# Django "more dyanmic" forms

Tags: django, dynamic, django-forms, dynamic-forms

I have a question about "more dynamic" django forms.

say, i have a webpage which represents Account with a list of users, so  each account will have 1 or more users, there is some javascript code  to generate extra row to allow user data gets entered.

i think this is pretty common use case, but not sure how to make it happen, or simply, i shouldn't worry about using django forms in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should use a [formset](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) for that. Specifically, you can use the [Inline formset factory](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) to achieve the same.

From the documentation of that,

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

>>> from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
>>> BookFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book)
>>> author = Author.objects.get(name=u'Mike Royko')
>>> formset = BookFormSet(instance=author)
```

If you are using the django-admin, you can display these inlines with the javascript to add a new entry, by using the [InlineModelAdmin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin) in either the stacked way, or tabular way.